# L'Hôpital's Rule contradicting with Theorem of Limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm a highschool student studying precalc, recently I encountered a simple limit problem, I found that using L'Hôpital's rule would give a wrong answer.

Problem:
$$
{\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x^2-4)}{(x^2+4)}}
$$
Using the Theorem of Limits, the answer is 0
$$
={\lim_{x\to2}\frac{((2^2-4)}{((2)^2+4)}} = \frac08 = 0
$$
However, using L'Hôpital's rule, I got 1 as answer
$$
{\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\frac {d}{dx}(x^2-4)}{\frac {d}{dx}(x^2+4)}}
$$
$$
{\lim_{x\to2}\frac{2x}{2x}}= \frac {2(2)}{2(2)}= \frac 44=1
$$

Anyone have any idea what mistakes I have made with L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is a theorem, and theorems have hypotheses. You did not check that your example satisfied those hypotheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cann not use Hospital, since $x^2+4 \to 8 \ne 0$ as $x \to 2.$

Comment: Got it. So it is only usable in cases that equal 0/0? (indeterminate?)

Comment: @NathanHung, not precisely. ${\infty \over \infty}$ is yet another valid case to use L'Hospital

Comment: @NathanHung For the $0/0$ case it is also important that the denominator is eventually non-zero in the direction that you're going.